# Pandas finding rows from column of list

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a large dataframe `df` which looks as following, where each value in column `Col2` is itself a list:

```
Col1  Col2
R1    ['C1']
R2    ['C1', 'C2']
R3    ['C1']
```

I want to get the following:

```
Col1  Col2
R1    ['C1']
R3    ['C1']
```

I am trying the following:

```
df[df['Col2'] == ['C1']]
```

But it is not generating desired results.

Edit: I am trying to get the rows where `Col2` contains the list with only values `['C1']` and not `['C1', 'C2']`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the equal operator with a list as pandas will try to use the list as a vector to match all elements of the Series.

Assuming you have a Series of lists, you can use:

```
df[[x==['C1'] for x in df['Col2']]]
```

or:

```
df[df['Col2'].str[0].eq('C1') & df['Col2'].str.len().eq(1)]
```

output:

```
  Col1  Col2
0   R1  [C1]
2   R3  [C1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it to string:

```
df[df['Col2'].astype(str).eq("['C1']")]
```

**Output:**

```
  Col1  Col2
0   R1  [C1]
2   R3  [C1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice you can always convert to `tuple`

```
df[df['Col2'].map(tuple)==('C1',)]
```